# Nasm - Assign array of bytes to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, struct, nasm

Assume I have an "array" (i know technically assembly doesn't have arrays) like

```
section .data USE32
bytes db 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ...
```

And a struct declared like that:

```
STRUC CONTEXT
.a RESD 1
.b RESD 1
.c RESD 1
ENDSTRUC
```

Is there a way to initialize my struct by assigning my "variable" bytes to it? Like an equivalent to the C/C++ way:

```
void* a = &abc;
struct_pointer sp = (struct_pointer) a;
```

Because when there a many structs, its really annoying to do it all by hand for every value.

Comment: See [section 4.12.10 in the manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.10). `nasm` doesn't really have structure support. All you get is offsets. So you can do `mov eax, [bytes+CONTEXT.b]`

Comment: The easiest approach is to use a program which translates the C structure offsets into #define's so your assembly code can be kept in sync with your C code.  It isn't pleasant, but the pain helps to minimize the binding in the interfaces, and that is almost certainly a good thing.

Comment: Using fancy assembler features is a mugs game, your source + build system will be better off if you treat the assembler as dumb and featureless.